# JSON in Android

Tags: android

I want to consume a json web service ,

this is the url  : http://10.0.2.2:8888/RESULT.JSON

```
{
"idpersonne":1,
"nom":"AAA",
"prenom":"AAA",
}
```

how I can retrieve the object "person" using android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
final URL url = new URL(path);
InputStream is = url.openStream();

final String jString = convertStreamToString(is);
final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jString);

final String jString = convertStreamToString(is);

final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jString);

long personId = jObject.getLong("idpersonne");
String nom = jObject.getString("nom");
String prenom = jObject.getString("prenom");
```

convertStreamToString method:

```
private String convertStreamToString(final InputStream is)
    {

        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try
        {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (final IOException e)
        {
            L.e(e.getMessage());

        } finally
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();

            } catch (final IOException e)
            {

                L.e(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Behold the [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), which reads `String`s and will let you pull pieces out by name.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse json strings. Read [this](http://albertattard.blogspot.com/2009/06/practical-example-of-gson.html) tutorial

Comment: The Android developer website recommends you use the JSONObject.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Gson is good enough to give a try